# can't connect to phpadmin/mysql using EasyPHP 5.3.5

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

> 2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's
>   socket is not correctly configured)

started getting this message when i try to connect to phpadmin from the EasyPHP admin panel ? I have not changed any configs that i'm aware of so i'm confused dont want to touch anything just yet in case i make it worse, mysql server seems to be running ok  any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to have resolved itself , so have no helpful info to add sorry !